# Can methodSignatureForSelector: create a "catch-all" method signature?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, objective-c-runtime

I am trying to make a catch-all proxy that takes any selector with any type of arguments and sends an RPC call down the wire. In this case, the signature of the method is not known because it can be created arbitrarily by the end user.

I see that the method signature requires supplying type encodings for each of the arguments. Is there a type encoding that signifies absolutely anything (pointer, int, everything else)? Otherwise, is there another way to accomplish this effect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"sort of", but not really... or, at least, not practically.

You can implement the method forwarding protocol such that unrecognized method calls will be wrapped up in an NSInvocation and then you could tear into the NSInvocation, but it really isn't practical for a number of reasons.

First, it only really works for relatively simple argument types.   The C ABI is such that complex arguments -- structures, C++ objects, etc.. -- can be encoded on the stack in wonky ways.   In fact, they can be encoded in ways where there isn't enough metadata to decode the frames.

Secondly, any kind of a system where "selectors can be created arbitrarily by the user" has a very distinct odor about it;  an odor of "you are doing it the hard way".   Objective-C, while exceptionally dynamic, was really not designed to support this level of pure meta-object pattern.

As well, any such resulting system is going to be exceptionally fragile.  What if the "arbitrary selector" happens to be, say, @selector(hash)?

Answer (score 2):

Can you describe in more detail about this catch-all proxy and what it needs to forward to?

If your proxy only needs to forward each message to one target, then it can do so in its `-forwardingTargetForSelector:` at runtime. If not (e.g. you need to forward to multiple targets or do other complicated manipulation), you need to implement `-forwardInvocation:` to handle it. Using `-forwardInvocation:` to handle calls requires you to implement `-messageSignatureForSelector:` because it needs to get the method signature in order to be able to create the invocation. (Even if you forward it to another object, that object also needs to either implement the method directly, add the method in response to `+resolveInstanceMethod:`, or handle it using `-forwardInvocation:`, all of which requires it to also have the signature.)

A method signature encodes the types of the arguments and return type. The reason that this information is needed for an invocation is that when these arguments are passed, they are laid out at compile-time (probably consecutively) in memory according to their types in the declaration. A large struct parameter is going to take up more space than an int parameter. A double is also probably bigger than an int. An invocation needs to store all of these arguments and let you access or change them by index. There is no way to figure out how the arguments are laid out at runtime unless you knew the types (or at least the sizes of the types).

Also, the message passing mechanism is different for methods that return structs (they call `objc_msgSend_stret`) from other methods (they call `objc_msgSend`) (and on some platforms, methods that return doubles use `objc_msgSend_fpret`). In the former case, the struct is not returned directly, but the location to write to is passed as an extra pointer argument as an out parameter. So knowing the return type is also critical to handling the call and the return value in the invocation.

Even if you are forwarding the invocation to some other object, ultimately that object (or some object it forwards to down the line) has to know the method signature somehow. So why not ask that object for the signature of the selector when you need it?

There is no "safe" signature that will work for all things, because different types have different sizes.